# SCRIPT5009: 'setShowCard' is undefined in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, struts-1

I'm getting the above error on one page in my Struts web application in IE10, but not in  chrome or firefox. Edit: doesn't work in any version of internet explorer

The javascript function that is apparently undefined is defined on the JSP that calls it. I have looked at other questions involving this error, but they all seem to be a problem with .Net or jQuery, which are not used in this page (though jQuery is used elsewhere in the application).

Here is a cut down version of the JSP:
(sorry it's still huge, I didn't write it, so couldn't be sure what wouldn't be relevant)

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/XXX" prefix="XXX" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>

<tiles:insert page="/templates/acceptance-layout.jsp" flush="false"> 
  <tiles:put name="pagename" value="paymentdetails" type="String" />
  <tiles:put name="errors" type="String"/>
  <tiles:put name="body" type="String">    

            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                <!-- 
                autoCompOff('PaymentDetailsForm'); 
                -->
                function setShowCard(value){
                    if(value != ""){
                        if(value == "F" || value == "O")                        
                        document.getElementById("isPageReloaded").value = "Y";  
                        else if(value == "N" || value == "S")
                        document.getElementById("isPageReloaded").value = "N";                  
                    }                                       
                }
            </script> 

            <html:form action="PaymentDetails" method="POST">

                <input type="hidden" id="redirectLink" name="redirectLink" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="totalprice" value="<bean:write name='wrapper' property='totalPrice' />" />
                <input type="hidden" name="paymentdetails.recalc" value="" />     
                <input type="hidden" id="showWaitertPage" name="showWaitertPage" value="md-loading"/>               

                <section class="content-main">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                       <div class="box box-summary">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <label for="cardowner" class="form-label">Whose card is this</label>

                                    <bean:define id="styleClass"><bean:write name="PaymentDetailsForm" property="styleClass" /></bean:define>
                                     <XXX:select  property="cardHolder" id="cardowner" styleClass="<%=styleClass %>"  onchange="setShowCard(this.value)" required ="required">
                                            <XXX:xxxOptionsCollection name="cardHolderList" />
                                            <input type="hidden" id="isPageReloaded"  name="pageReload" value="N" />
                                     </XXX:select> 
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- END .inner-content -->  
                </section>
                    <script>
                        applyCreditCardCharge(document.PaymentDetailsForm,document.PaymentDetailsForm.cardType.value);
                    </script>

            </html:form>

    </tiles:put>
</tiles:insert>
```

And here is the html that I get from the developer tools on IE10:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- HTML5 Boilerplate -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js gt-ie8" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="http://XXX/pages/paymentdetails.jsp">

            <script src="scripts/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/util.js?v1.9"></script>
            <script src="scripts/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/form.js?v1.0"></script>

<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
</head>

<body id="top" class="annual js-form">
<div id="outer-wrap">

            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                <!-- 
                autoCompOff('PaymentDetailsForm'); 
                -->
                function setShowCard(value){
                console.log("got here");
                    if(value != ""){
                        if(value == "F" || value == "O")                        
                        document.getElementById("isPageReloaded").value = "Y";  
                        else if(value == "N" || value == "S")
                        document.getElementById("isPageReloaded").value = "N";                  
                    }                                       
                }
            </script> 

            <form name="PaymentDetailsForm" method="POST" action="/XXX/PaymentDetails.do">

                <input type="hidden" id="redirectLink" name="redirectLink" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" name="totalprice" value="1963.66" />
                <input type="hidden" name="paymentdetails.recalc" value="" />     
                <input type="hidden" id="showWaitertPage" name="showWaitertPage" value="md-loading"/>               

                <section class="content-main">
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <div class="box box-editable editing js-show-hide">
                            <div class="box-body">                              
                                <div class="form-row editable js-ufs">
                                    <label for="cardowner" class="form-label">Whose card is this</label>                                    
                                     <select name="cardHolder" id="cardowner" required="required" onchange="setShowCard(this.value)" class="js-ufs-trigger"><option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="N">User</option>
<option value="S">Partner/Spouse</option>
<option value="F">Family member</option>
<option value="O">Other</option>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="isPageReloaded"  name="pageReload" value="N" /></select> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                  
                    </div> <!-- END .inner-content -->  
                </section>

                    <script>
                        applyCreditCardCharge(document.PaymentDetailsForm,document.PaymentDetailsForm.cardType.value);
                    </script>
            </form>        
</div>
            <script src="scripts/helpers.js"></script>
            <script src="scripts/conditional-loader.js?v0.9"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to move the autoCompOff method below the method that wasn't being found. If anyone knows I'd love to know why that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.

Error; SCRIPT5009: 'submit' is undefined in internet explorer

Here 'submit' is the id of my submit button.

This line was throwing the error:

```
$(submit).click(function() {
```

I changed it to:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
```

It works on IE now. Hope this helps someone there...

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` element is already protected, meaning that it's a section that doesn't follow the HTML parsing criteria. One can have a variable, `var a = "Hello"` (double quotes) and the HTML parser won't break.

Unfortunately, the comment block section won't work in the `script` element:

```
<!-- -->
```

If you want to comment out a function, use the C++ style double forward-slash, like so:

```
//autoCompOff('PaymentDetailsForm');
```

I hope this helps.